# Marketing Cloud API - Replicating Triggered Send Functionality

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, api

Scenario: Customer information is imported into the Marketing Cloud daily into a Data Extension. This Data Extension contains is all users who have made a purchase.

Added to that, a newsletter signup form also exists that subscribers directs into the Marketing Cloud. Since I'm using a Data Extension model, it seems that using a Triggered Send Definition to add that user into another Data Extension and send a welcome email is the obvious choice.

But let's say I wanted all these subscribers to live in that same customer Data Extension and not split them up into two. Could I use an API on the signup form to insert them into the customer Data Extension, while simultaneously using another API to send them a Welcome Email?

I know of there is API functionality that can handle these two tasks independently, but would I be able to combine then to create the same effect as the Triggered Send Definition?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that newsletter signup form a SmartCapture form? 
If yes, you can link it directly with your Customer Data Extension.
If No, you can still use REST API on the signup form to insert records into Customer DE and then another API call can trigger the Email Send

Another way is to write a Query Activity to load data from Newsletter DE to Customer DE. You can invoke this Query using API and then use another API for Welcome Email

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the help - that's somewhat what I was thinking of. It seems there are multiple options of getting around this, and none are necessarily perfect. Thanks again!